# Does civilians' defence of their cities absolve advancing soldiers of war crimes?

Tags: military, laws-of-war, the-hague

What are the consequences of civilians picking up arms (such as Molotov cocktails) to defend their cities?

By giving orders for the Russian military to fire on civilians in cities, those who issue the order and the soldiers would be culpable for war crimes.

It would appear that Ukrainian civilians have every right to defend their cities by attacking advancing soldiers using all means at their disposal.

Does civilians' defence of their cities absolve advancing soldiers of war crimes?

#### Clarification

The question is not about the fate of the civilians, but that of the soldiers.

Let's look at a more distant example.

Under command from the Nazi or the Soviet leadership, soldiers were given orders to enter residential neighborhoods, kill some civilians, and capture others—sending them to Nazi extermination camps or the Gulag.

After the hostilities ended some soldiers and some civilians survived. The soldiers are prosecuted at Nuremberg or The Hague, and some civilians are ready to testify as eyewitnesses pinpointing the attacking soldiers. Is a defence of "*but the civilians I was shooting/capturing were actively throwing Molotov cocktails on me, and hence they were legitimate targets*" a viable defence against a war crimes charge?

Comment: Combatants are combatants regardless of their employment status

Comment: @Rick I assume that would apply to civilians who voluntarily became combatants. Not to other civilians, and not to civilians who act in self defence.

Comment: Note that using cluster bombs and thermobaric bombs is _always_ a war crime, whether against civilians or against regular soldiers. And both seem to have happened.

Comment: @gnasher729 Since when use of a cluster bomb against regular soldiers is a war crime? Neither USA, Russia nor Ukraine is a party of the Convention on Cluster Munitions.

Answer (score 10):

### Civilians taking active part in hostilities are legitimate targets

This is enshrined in [Rule 6](https://ihl-databases.icrc.org/customary-ihl/eng/docindex/v1_rul_rule6) of customary International Humanitarian Law.

> Rule 6. Civilians are protected against attack, unless and for such time as they take a direct part in hostilities.

Comment: In other words you're saying that a Russian soldier who shoots (and kills) Ukrainian civilians has committed a war crime, but not if the civilians stood their grounds and were actively defending their residences instead of fleeing. Can you clarify?

Comment: Attacking a civilian's home just to cause damages wouldn't count as "hostilities". That residence isn't a legitimate target. So the civilian wouldn't take part in hostilities.

Comment: @Sam I would think the sentence is sufficiently clear

Comment: @DaleM I would disagree. The sentence leaves a scenario open which seems counter-intuitive and should be clarified. That scenario is the following: "A soldier instigates hostilities. A civilian acts in self-defense, thus taking part in hostilities (in at least one sense of the word). During their act of self-defense, it would thus not be a war crime to attack the civilian, as they are in that moment, taking part in hostilities". The soldier that instigated would probably have comitted a war crime due to the instigation, but what about attacks by any soldier after the self-defence has begun?

Comment: Self-defense is not hostilities

Comment: In other words: the hostilities need to start from the civilian side to make them combatants.

Comment: @Trish no. Hostilities are what happens in armed conflict - without hostilities there is no conflict. There can be murder and assault and self-defence and all the sorts of things that happen outside armed conflict but the actual business of warfighting, the hostilities, are what combatants engage it.

Comment: How about defense of others - is it a hostility? A soldier tries to rape a wife/daughter. A husband/father defends her and is shot dead. Is the soldier who shot him (not necessarily the rapist) excused?

Answer (score 3):

**Not exactly.**

Civilians fighting in accordance with the laws of war (wearing distinctive insigniga, bearing arms openly, etc.) would become combatants. The rule was written exactly for a situation like this, the population of an invaded country rallying to support their armed forces. As I understand it, a blue-and-yellow cloth on the arm should be enough distinction.

That makes shooting them *not* a war crime, under the same circumstances which apply to enemy soldiers. In other circumstances, shooting them would be a war crime. Russian soldiers would still be responsible for any war crimes they commit.

Comment: Does it mean that shooting a civilian fighting while not wearing insignia, concealing weapon etc. is a war crime?

Comment: @abukaj, it would be a war crime to attack civilians intentionally. When it is either an accident/misidentification or collateral damage from an attack on a military target, it becomes a question of proportionality and the attempt of distinction.

Comment: Even if the mentioned civilian attacks soldiers? I mean a situation when someone not wearing any insignia draws his concealed weapon and starts shooting members of occupying forces.

Comment: @abukaj, then the civilian would be violating the laws of war. To become a combatant, he must carry weapons openly and wear distinctive insignia.

Comment: So is shooting them a war crime? I asked that particular question, as your answer implies it is only legal to shoot a combatant.

Comment: @abukaj, your "them" depends on which part of my answer you refer to. Shooting civilians who spontaneously form a militia is not a war crime under the same rules when shooting soldiers is not a war crime. Shooting civilians while they are fighting with concealed weapons is not a war crime, but when they are no longer fighting they should get a trial rather than being shot.